# Custom JpaRepository no found property saveEntity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

You need to create a generic JpaRepository, in order to handle all transactions made by the system. Follow this example [here](https://github.com/jkubrynski/spring-data-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/com/kubrynski/data/repository/generic).

It was a bit different from the implementation, because my goal is not to do a search but to manipulate a save method.

Inteface GenericRepository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    <S extends T> S saveEntity(S entity);
}
```

Class GenericRepositoryFactory :

```
public class GenericRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory}.
     *
     * @param entityManager must not be {@literal null}
     */
    public GenericRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
        return GenericRepositoryImpl.class;
    }
}
```

Class GenericRepositoryFactoryBean:

```
public class GenericRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends JpaRepository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable>
    extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link JpaRepositoryFactoryBean} for the given repository interface.
     *
     * @param repositoryInterface must not be {@literal null}.
     */
    public GenericRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a {@link org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport}.
     *
     * @param entityManager
     * @return
     */
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new GenericRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    }
}
```

Class GenericRepositoryImpl:

```
public class GenericRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements GenericRepository<T, ID> {

    private JpaEntityInformation<T, Serializable> entityInformation;
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public GenericRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, Serializable> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }


    @Override
    public T saveEntity(Object entity) {
        //here custom code...
        return null;
    }
}
```

My inteface using my generic repository:

```
public interface SistemaMenuRepository extends GenericRepository<SistemaMenu, Integer> {
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class SistemaMenuService {
    @Autowired
    SistemaMenuRepository sistemaMenuRepository;
}
```

Generates following error to run application:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sistemaMenuService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'sistemaMenuRepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sistemaMenuRepository': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property saveEntity found for type SistemaMenu!

Any helpe it´s welcome!

Comment: Is there a link to an example missing? How do you put the infrastructure to use?

Comment: Sorry, I have already corrected the link. On your question, I do not know if you managed to understand very well, but have not yet implemented the use of the saveEntidade method, come the error when compiling the project.

Comment: You show a RepositoryFactory and a RepositoryFactoryBean. You have to tell spring to use those. How have you done that? Something like this: https://github.com/jkubrynski/spring-data-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kubrynski/data/config/DataConfig.java

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jens you need to specify your custom repository factory bean class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories( basePackages = "repository.packagename",
                        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
                        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
                        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = GenericRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfiguration {
...
}
```